# Python pandas: how to get hour from timestamp in dataframe?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a dataframe called DF that looks like this

```
time                     blah
2013-01-17 8:30          blah blah
2013-01-17 9:30          blah blah
```

The elements under time is of TimeStamp class. I want to grab all rows with hour == 8. How do I do it?

In R, it would be like this

```
DF[DF$time$hour == 8,]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on [`Timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps), or just tried `help(Timestamp)` or `help(my_timestamp_instance)` in the interactive interpreter?

Comment: Also, do you know how to filter dataframes in general, but don't know "how to get hour from timestamp" as your question title says, or do you not know how to use dataframes in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I know how timestamp works. The problem is that I am querying hour from a LIST of the object, not the object itself. For example, I can get the hour by doing DF.time[0] == 8. This would return 1 boolean value but what I want is a list of booleans.

Comment: You don't (or at least shouldn't) ever have a list of anything in Pandas; you have either a DateFrame, a Series, an Index, or an array. Assuming you have a Series or Index, this is easy; if you, e.g., have an array instead, then what you want to do is get a Series or Index instead of an array. It's hard to explain what you need to change to do that without seeing your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few places you could be getting stuck here, and without code it's hard to know which one. So let's go through one by one.

Note that most of this is explained in the documentation on [`TimeSeries`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries) (which also covers related classes like `Timestamp`, with relevant links where necessary), which will probably do a better job than I or anyone else on StackOverflow is likely to do…

Anyway, if you have a `TimeSeries` (or any series of Pandas objects), you can just access the members of the `Timestamp` (or other) objects through normal dot-attribute syntax and get back a new series or array, as appropriate. So, for example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'blah': ('blah', 'blah')}, index=(pd.Timestamp('201301170830'), pd.Timestamp('201301070930'))
>>> ts = df.index
>>> ts.hour
array([8, 9])
```

So, if you want to get an array of booleans:

```
>>> df.index.hour == 8
array([True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Now, there are a zillion ways to select things in pandas (see the tutorial section on [Selection](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection)), but one way to do it is:

```
>>> df[df.index.hour == 8]
                     blah
2013-01-17 08:30:00  blah
```

Is that what you're looking for?